# merging events indices with time vectors Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two vectors.

`time = [0:100];`

`events = [2,4,5,10,22,33,34,35,66,69,72,77,81,99];`

I would like to know how to make a new vector that is binary, where in each index position (1-101), there is either a 0 or a 1, representing the absence or presence of an event.

This new vector will be length(time) and will look something like this (only first 10 positions shown):

```
new = [0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,....];
```

Ultimately this "new" vector will be used to sum events within a rolling window to determine frequency of an event per unit time.

Comment: The [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function is, what you're looking for: `ismember(time, events)` should do the trick.

Comment: Are the elements in `events` time instances, or indices of time instances in the `time` vector? In the first case, the solution from @HansHirse works fine. In the second case (which is what you showed in your desired output `new`) you could use `ismember(1:numel(time), events)`. For your particular example these solutions are off by 1 position.